# $ f:\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ such that $ x t f(t,x) < 0 $ and solution to $ x' = f(t,x) $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm starting with differential equations course and I can't solve this problem:

$ f:\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ such that $ x t f(t,x) < 0 $ when $ xt \neq 0 $. Can we say that exists at most one solution of $ x' = f(t,x) $ such that $x(0)=0$? And if $f$ is continous?

I only read the first chapter of "Lições de equações diferenciais ordinárias" from Sotomayor.

Comment: $f(t,x) = - \frac{1}{tx}$ has the desired property and certainly isn't continuous everywhere in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: @Edwin Thank you. But how I can prove that exists at max one solution with $x(0)=0$?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with your book, but in general if you can assume $f(t,x)$ is continuous in $t$ and it is Lipschitz in $x(t)$. then Picard's existence theorem gives you this result.

Comment: @Edwin yes, I have the Picard's theorem, but I can't understand what to do with the example, are you saying that have more than one maximal solution with x(0)=0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning the case where $f$ is continuous. If $x$ is a solution to the initial value problem above, then
$$
\frac12 t(x^2)'=tx\dot{x} = txf(x,t) < 0, \quad tx\neq0
$$
Then, for $t>0$, $(x^2)'\leq0$ and so 
$$x^2(t)-x^2(\varepsilon)\leq0$$
 for all $\varepsilon>0$. Leting $\varepsilon\rightarrow0$, 
$$x^2(t)\leq0$$
So  $x\equiv0$, which then requires $f$ to also satisfy $f(0,t)=0$ for all $t$.

Comment: First, thank you. And then if f is continous we can conclude that the only solution with $x(0) = 0$ have to be $x \equiv 0$?

Comment: Yes. First if $f$ is continuous you know there are solutions to the initial value problem. Taking any such solution, by arguing as above, you realized that it is necessary for $f$ to satisfy the additional property $f(0,t)=0$ for all $t$, and for $x(t)\equiv0$.

Comment: Really thank you. And if f is not continous have another idea?

Comment: A similar argument shows that if there is solution, then it must be 0. The issue is that there might be cases where there is not solution. The example that Edwin mentioned, $f(x,t)=-\frac{1}{xt}$, $xt\neq0$ is one of them.

Comment: Sorry but now I miss why for $t>0$, $(x^2)' \leq 0$ implies $x^2(t) - x^2(\varepsilon) \leq 0$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$

Comment: integrate over the interval $(\varepsilon,t]$